# Convert from Geometry to SDE Binary storage type in SDE database

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, convert, sql-server

We have been battling performance issues between SQL 2012 and ArcGIS 10.1. One of the most common solution is to convert to SDE Binary storage. We know that this storage type is not as dynamic as the Geometry type. But we just opted to try to convert atleast one table in the database (assuming that it is possible).

Problem is, we are not sure on the correct procedure to do this. Do we do it on the database side? or in the ArcGIS side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to copy the original feature class to a new one, specifying a DBTUNE keyword that will use SDEBINARY storage.  There's probably a dozen additional ways, but they all involve a query and new table creation.

Comment: Hi vince, i tried the import tool on the arccatalog connection in arcmap to the sde database and specifying the keyword to SDEBinary but i always encounter this error "000597 : Failed to insert input record with FeatureID <value>." i tried the import feature class and import table but the same error occurs. I also checked the DBtune table and there is a SDEBinary keyword present. Although the default Geometry_Storage is set to Geometry.

Comment: You've got a quirky situation with your data to resolve.  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//00vp00000015000597.htm

Comment: Hi Vince, i was able to import the feature class successfully by changing the field mapping for the SHAPE column data type from DOUBLE to LONG. Although im curious as to why the resulting table in SQL produces the SHAPE column as of type INT. Is that the expected type for SDEBinary storage? I was able to load the imported feature class in ArcMap.

Comment: SDEBINARY storage uses an auxillary tables (Fn & Sn) to store the geometry BLOB and the spatial index (respectively).  The integer in the business table "shape" column is a foreign key into the F and S tables.